# Python Tkinter Record Strings

Tags: python, tkinter

i am new at python.I have 3 Accelerometer Values.X axis Y axis and Z axis.
I can monitoring them via these codes below:

```
from liblo import *
from tkinter import*

import sys 
import time
    @make_method('/muse/acc', 'fff')
        def acc_callback(self, path, args):
            acc_x, acc_y, acc_z = args
            print "%s %f %f %f" % (path, acc_x, acc_y, acc_z)
def Record():
.......
.......
```

However,i want to record them via tkinter/record button

```
R = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Record", command = Record)
R.pack()
```

How can i record these datas via button?Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "record?"

Comment: record 3 different axis strings when click record button

Comment: What do you want it constantly recording till you click it again? where do you want the recordings to go? what format? just print? we need more than just `def Record(): [...]` to work with...

Comment: ok.I want  to save it when I click on the button at desktop as .csv file.I know,we have more thans def Record(): [...] I already need help at that point

Comment: So you want to save those three inputs everytime you click record. Not realtime..? Just one click = one row of data

Comment: Yes, i want to record when i clicked

Comment: Think about how you would tackle this problem. Simply return those 4 variables. and then inject it into the record function. Where the record function would simply write the to params as input to a csv file...

Comment: We cant do all of this for you, you need to make some attempt on your own

Comment: Funny,anyway thanks..

Comment: @erugrulgaziortaokulu I think the only funny thing here is the complete and utter lack of effort and understanding you have demonstrated.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your attention.Have a nice day.Stop.

Answer (score 0):

I've written out a working example of how you can do this with tkinter below:

```
from tkinter import *
import csv

open("file.csv", "w")

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.array = [0, 1, 2]
        self.button = Button(self.root, text="Save", command=self.command)
        self.button.pack()
    def command(self):
        with open("file.csv", "a") as f:
            csv.writer(f).writerow(self.array)
        for i in range(len(self.array)):
            self.array[i] = self.array[i]+1

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Essentially all we're doing is using the `csv` module to write a new row for every button push.